# how to store and reuse a timeout in a jQuery event handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button, when clicked it will start a timeout function, if it is clicked again before the function is executed, I want the former timeout to be cleared thus it can start a new timeout.

Demonstration code:

```
<div id='a'>lorem</div>

$('#a').click(function(){
  //code to clear previous timeout
  //This is not working: clearTimeout(timeout);
  var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
   //do something
  },5000);
  return timeout;    
})
```

The only way I can think of is make `timeout` global, but global is ugly.

Is there any better way to do this? And in the above codes, where is `timeout` being returned to? In which scope I can use it?

Comment: Use an IIFE or module pattern (ie. put the JavaScript code to add the click in a function) to make the timeout a non-global variable in an outer (and longer lasting) scope.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: For the secondary question: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184276/return-false-from-jquery-click-event and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379403/jquery-event-handlers-return-values?rq=1 for the returned value meaning (and how to do as much in a 'modern way', although returning false will still work, but timeout will never be a falsey value so..)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two alternatives to global variables that you can use here :

**1** an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) creating a local scope :

```
(function(){
    var timer;
    $('#a').click(function(){
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(function(){
          //do something
      },5000);
    })
})();
```

**2** jquery data attached to the element

```
$('#a').click(function(){
  clearTimeout($(this).data('timer'));
  $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(function(){
      //do something
  },5000));
})
```

Comment: method 2 not work on JQ 3.1.0+: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'guid' on number '1'