# jQuery: Delay a function from being used again once fired for a set time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want my function to fire on scroll, but **then** wait 250ms until it may fire again.

```
function myFunction() {
    console.log('hello');
}

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
        myFunction();
});
```

I have tried a timeout:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        myFunction();
    }, 250);
});
```

However this method delays for 250ms **before** firing the function.

Comment: This is `throttle` you can also `debounce`, which will fire the event after timeout only if it's not been raised within the timeout (ie each event resets the timeout then it only gets "fully" fired if none have been raised during the timeout)

Comment: With throttle, you get an event then don't get any more within the timeout.  In your case, you'd get the first scroll, then lose the remaining.  Depends on what `myFunction()` does - if it looks at the scroll position, then you'll want to debounce to ensure you get the last/final event not the first.

Comment: There's various answers already on SO, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424752/jquery-change-with-delay it's unclear exactly which would suit you

Comment: Based on [this answer] you can clear the "doing" variable in the timeout.  https://jsfiddle.net/Lazf4jkc/  this will give you the first event immediately then no other events for 250ms - with this method you will not get the last event.

Comment: @freedomn-m, the jsfiddle is exactly what I was looking for thank you.

Comment: Just noted I missed the link to the original - I'll add an answer as it's not exactly the same, just based on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7373113/2181514), you can add a flag so that additional events are not fired, then clear that flag using a timeout.

Note that this will lose/drop events within the timeout, so should not be used for something like user keyboard input; where *debounce* would be more suitable.

```js
var active = false;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if (active) return;
    active = true;
    
    myFunction();
    setTimeout(function() {
        active = false;
    }, 250);
});

function myFunction() { console.log("scroll"); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style='height:30000px;'>
something to scroll
</div>
```

This is a basic throttle implementation.  Improvements would be to make it modular / namespace'd and/or store the "active" flag on the element itself; so that it the same event can be reused for multiple elements and doesn't create lots of global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Simply call your function once outside of `setTimeout`.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    myFunction(); // call once

    setTimeout(function() {
        myFunction();
    }, 250); // repeat call after 250ms
});
```

Use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` if you want repeated calls every 250ms.