# Running a function after a set amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a registration form, and i want to dynamically check for the submitted user name availability using AJAX. 
So far i've made a input field with an OnKeyUp event which calls a function named `reg_un_check();`
Problem is, at the current setting, which works fine, the function runs every key stroke.
I wanna make some kind of "delay" between the keystrokes and the function call to let the user finish typing and save some bandwidth.
I tried using `SetTimeout()` but it only delays the time it takes between the AJAX requests.
This is what i've made so far:

Input Field:

```
<input type="text" value="user name" id="reg_un" onclick="reg_un_in()" onblur="reg_un_out()" onkeyup="reg_un_check()">
<div class="alerts" id="reg_un_alert"></div> // div that pops out if the UN isnt valid
<div class="reg_unc" id="reg_unc_alert"></div> // div that pops out when its checking for the availability
```

The AJAX function:

```
function reg_un_check(){
    if(reg_un.value.length > 1){
        $("#reg_un_alert").slideUp(150);
        var un_data = "un=" + reg_un.value;
        $("#reg_unc_alert").slideDown(150,function () {
            var un_check = setTimeout(function(){
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                        reg_unc_alert.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }                                               
                    else{
                        reg_unc_alert.innerHTML = "checking for availability...";                           
                    }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("POST",'un_check.php',true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttp.send(un_data);                      
            },2000);            
        });
    }
    else{
        $("#reg_unc_alert").slideUp(150);
        reg_un_alert.innerHTML = "the user name must be at least 2 characters long";
        $("#reg_un_alert").slideDown(150);
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a different or a better way to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Because you do not cancel the timeout.... Bunch of dupes with the same problem, time to find one.

Comment: Not a fan of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373023/throttle-event-calls-in-jquery still looking for a better one.

Comment: it always amazes me that some people will use jQuery for the DOM, but then hand-craft `XMLHttpRequest` objects to do their AJAX.

Comment: NB: the keyword you need to search for is _debounce_

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220126/run-javascript-function-when-user-finishes-typing-instead-of-on-key-up

Comment: @Alnitak what do you mean? i only used jQuery for the sliding effects...

Comment: @Alex I mean that jQuery includes a much of AJAX related functions that would make that part of your code utterly trivial. `$.post('un_check.php', {un: reg_un.value}).then(function(html) { reg_unc_alert.innerHTML = html });`

Answer (score 1):

It's a very common concept in javascript, called debouncing, lodash library has it: https://lodash.com/docs#debounce

A simple way to make it your self is like this:

```
var timeoutId;
function debounceFunction() {
   clearTimeout(timeoutId); //no worries if timeoutid is undefined
   timeoutId = setTimeout(delayedWorkFunction, delay);
}
```

A more complicated way, but a more generalized way to do it is to have a function that receives a function and a delay, and returns a function that on invocation will execute that function with the delay and cancel calls that were made before the delay has passed (i.e. what lodash debounce function does).

```
 function debounce(cb, delay) {
      var tId;
      var retFunc = function() {
          clearTimeout(tId);
          setTimeout(cb, delay);
      }
      return retFunc;
  }

function work() {
     //your logic here
}

var delayedWork = debounce(work, 150);
//now calling delayedWork will do what you want
```

Hope I didn't over complicate it.

Comment: Just FYI, debouncing and throttling are two slightly different concepts. Debouncing waits until an action hasn't been repeated in a certain amount of time (which is what you are showing correctly), throttling limits the amount of times an action can be repeated in a given amount of time. http://drupalmotion.com/article/debounce-and-throttle-visual-explanation

Comment: Oh ok, now the names make sense :) Edited to reflect what you said.